# Jquery Autocomplete Change Event Not Setting Focus Of Specified Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I've literally tried everything I can think of but cant figure out why this is not setting focus to the input I specify.

What im trying to do is whenever a autocomplete item is selected from the list it should set focus to the #areyoufrom input

The page can be found here http://mysmart.travel Autocomplete is working as expected but just will not change focus.

This is the code i am using to fire the change event and it logs to the console fine but does not set focus on the other input.

```
$( "#areyourfrom" ).autocomplete({
   change: function(event, ui) { 
     $("#areyourgoing").focus();
     console.log(change);
   }
});
```

The data is being pulled from a external source and works fine but for some reason I get a error

```
TypeError: this.source is not a function
```

I'm not sure if this is related to the autocomplete not changing focus to the other input though.

Comment: PS you've got a stray XML doctype tag appearing before your HTML doctype tag.

Comment: You're also including 2 different versions of jQuery... is this intentional? (1.7 and 1.8.3)

Comment: Im not sure right now honestly, i just recieved this project from someone else its a joomla site that they made like 2 years ago and decided to revive it now and i cant get a hold of the old dev so im just working through it all now

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not define the source attribute and it is therefore NULL.  Check [the documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) and define your source.  Otherwise it's not able to even get to your code.

To see this, in Chrome, I activated the developer tools.  Selected the option to pause on exceptions, waited for the exception, checked the stack trace and since it didn't have anything to do with what you presented, I examined the source to find jquery-ui.js line 6249 setting the value to `null` which queued me in that it must be an overridable setting... and that led me to the documentation.

Yes, a bit of a roundabout way of finding where to go, but that's the nature of the beast! :)

Comment: Thank you ill see what i can do to fix that now, this site is really old and i had to take over from the old developer so everything is all scattered:( Do you think that this would solve the focus problem that I am having though? I dont understand why it would still register the change event to the console but not fire the focus.

Comment: There are so many lines of code between what is there and what is included that I can't begin to guess at what the fundamental cause is.  But the rules of programming say start at the first b/c you never know how many more disappear once it is solved.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out I was able to fix the typekit error:) still have to figure out about this focus nonsense though

Comment: After you accept my answer, my I suggest Ctrl+F5?  The field becomes active when I do a search for "New Y" and click on "New York, NY - All airports ".